# How to mock a future method and not get type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<>' in flutter

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, mocking, mockito

I want to mock this class and this specific method

```
class FeedApiService extends ApiService {
  Future<FeedResponse> fetchFeed(Map<String, String> params) async {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

My unit test is like this

```
class FeedApiServiceMock extends Mock implements FeedApiService {}
void main() {
  test('..', () {
    FeedApiServiceMock feedApiServiceMock = FeedApiServiceMock();
    when(feedApiServiceMock.fetchFeed({})).thenAnswer(
        (_) => Future.value(FeedResponse(items: 1)),
      );
    expect(await feedApiServiceMock.fetchFeed({}).items, 1);
  });
}
```

I just want to see that fetch feed is mocked correctly, but I'm getting this error:

```
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<FeedResponse>'
```

Comment: Do you have null-safety enabled?  If so, you now need to use `@GenerateMocks`.  See the [`README.md`](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) file (or [the `NULL_SAFETY_README.md`](https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/master/NULL_SAFETY_README.md) for more details).

Comment: Yes, I have null-safety enabled. I will try with @GenerateMocks and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: It worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See if adding async in both the test and `thenAnswer` method solves the problem.

```
void main() {
  test('..', () async{
    FeedApiServiceMock feedApiServiceMock = FeedApiServiceMock();
    when(feedApiServiceMock.fetchFeed({})).thenAnswer(
        (_) async=> Future.value(FeedResponse(items: 1)),
      );
    expect(await feedApiServiceMock.fetchFeed({}).items, 1);
  });
}
```

Comment: Nope, this does not work, unfortunately. It gives me the same error.